# Give an example of a function $f: A \to B$ that is onto, but not one-to-one.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$A$ is the set of $\{1,2,3\}$ and $B$ is the set of $\{2,3,4,5\}$

I understand that I need a function that can make everything that is in the set of B but I can't figure out how to not make it one to one

Comment: Since $A$ is smaller than $B$, it should be impossible to find an onto function from $A$ to $B$ -- are you sure you've understood the question correctly?

Comment: That is what I though as well. I typed in the question as directly as possible. I will email the professor now. Thanks guys!